# How to run artisan server forever on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu-16.04, laravel-5.6

I have up php artisan server on AWS Ubuntu server, but after ssh timeout artisan server goes down.

May I know how to start php artisan server forever on the AWS EC2 Ubuntu server?

Comment: Why not use Nginx or Apache?

Comment: i used Apache but show only "This page isn’t working
18.223.0.215 is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500"

Comment: Have you even tried setting up a server following the requirements for Laravel? Just a simple webserver does not suffice. Maybe read some documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/installation
I would suggest NOT to use `php artisan serve` for a production environment. Also, if you get errors you could probaby check some logs for details (NGINX/Apache logs, PHP logs, Laravel Logs).